# Close All Child Windows with Caliburn Micro using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a WPF MVVM application. I use the `WindowManager` to open and display a veiw. My main shell view model is as follows with the `SomeMethod` that displays the `ConsoleView`

```
[Export(typeof(IShell))]
public sealed class ShellViewModel : 
    Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive, IShell, IDataErrorInfo
{
    IWindowManager windowManager = null;
    ...
    public SomeMethod()
    {
        ...
        dynamic eo = new ExpandoObject();
        eo.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        ConsoleViewModel console = new ConsoleViewModel("Binary Table Compilation Output");
        windowManager.ShowWindow(console, null, eo);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and the `ConsoleViewModel` is

```
[View(typeof(ConsoleView))]
public class ConsoleViewModel : Screen
{
    ...
}
```

The problem is that if I shutdown the main application, the `ConsoleView` does not close. The question, how can I force all child windows to shutdown when the main application/shell does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add an event handler to the [`Window.Closed` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closed(v=vs.110).aspx) and close all open `Window`s from there:

```
public void MainWindowClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        window.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, yeah, but I thought that there would be a MVVM 'Caliburn way'?

Comment: Using Caliburn does *not* mean that you can't use .NET classes.

Comment: +1 for help. Appreciated. Just a quick one. I am happy to use this, but there are 4 windows that are showing up from `Application.Current.Windows` that are not visible and I have no clue what they are!? The main window is there at position one, but there are others instances of windows that I have not instantiated. Any idea why these are there?

Comment: I don't, but if they've been opened by your application (or underlying Framework), then you probably should close them anyway... just make sure that you close the `MainWindow` last.